# How to work out the degrees of freedom for residual in 2 way anova

Tags: anova

I have a formula that says to work out DF for residuals, I need to do  (n-1)IJ. Here I and J the number of levels in the two factors, but I haven't got a clue what n is. I thought it was total sample size but when I do that I get the wrong answer. Then I thought it might be number of people in each group, but again, this gives me the wrong answer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What was wrong when you used $n$ as the number of people in each group? Can you give the formula you have, the residual DF from whatever other source you're checking it against, the number of levels $i$ & $j$ of your 2 factors, & the number of people in each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is the number of replicates of each treatment - how many times each unique IJ combination is replicated.